# Regex add a space between words that ends before the letter S with succeeding numbers or before the character <

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to achieve this with re.sub.

```
Input1: RICHARDJAMESS1234567A

Output1: RICHARDJAMES S1234567A

Input2: ALFAROMEO<P>

Output2: ALFAROMEO <P>
```

I have tried this code but it isn't working.

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])([Ss]+(\d{7}|<)$', r'\1 ', report)
```

what are the changes I should be making in order to make this work?

Comment: In your first example, there's also a letter (`A`) after the S/number bit

Comment: Yes that's a legit example

Comment: Replace (zero-width) matches of the following regex with a single space: `(?=S\d|<[^<>]+>)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5C8WiU/1). `(?=S\d|<)` might suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the start index of the marker and split your string there:

```py
import re

def separate(text):
    match = re.search(r'(S\d+|<)', text)
    if match:
        idx = match.start()
        return text[:idx] + ' ' + text[idx:]
    return text

print(separate('RICHARDJAMESS1234567A'))
print(separate('ALFAROMEO<P>'))
```

gives

```
RICHARDJAMES S1234567A
ALFAROMEO <P>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
text = re.sub(r'S\d|<', r' \g<0>', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8CK7Sh/1).

The `S\d|<` matches `S` and a digit or a `<` char, and the whole match is replaced with a space  + itself.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ijt0cY):

```py
import re
text = "RICHARDJAMESS1234567A ALFAROMEO<P>"
print( re.sub(r"S\d|<", r" \g<0>", text) )
# => RICHARDJAMES S1234567A ALFAROMEO <P>
```